# Use a mix of user provided values and defaults

Tags: terraform

I am trying to setup a module so that I can allow sensible defaults to be used so users don't need to need manually specify all values.

​

Here is an example of where I was thinking this could be used:

​

`modules/network_acls/main.tf`

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "this" {
  for_each                    = var.network_acls
  priority                    = each.value.priority
  direction                   = each.value.direction
  access                      = each.value.access
  protocol                    = each.value.protocol
  source_port_range           = local.network_acls.source_port_range
  destination_port_range      = local.network_acls.destination_port_range
  source_address_prefix       = local.network_acls.source_address_prefix
  destination_address_prefix  = local.network_acls.destination_address_prefix
  name                        = each.key
  network_security_group_name = local.network_acls.network_security_group_name
  resource_group_name         = local.network_acls.resource_group_name
}
```

​

`modules/network_acls/variables.tf`

```
variable "network_acls" {
  description = ""
  type = map(object({
    network_security_group_name = string
    resource_group_name         = string
    priority                    = number
    direction                   = string
    access                      = optional(string)
    protocol                    = optional(string)
    source_port_range           = optional(string)
    destination_port_range      = optional(string)
    source_address_prefix       = optional(string)
    destination_address_prefix  = optional(string)
    }
  ))
}

locals {
  network_acls = defaults(var.network_acls, {
    access                      = "Deny"
    protocol                    = "*"
    source_port_range           = "*"
    destination_port_range      = "*"
    source_address_prefix       = "*"
    destination_address_prefix  = "*"}
  )
}
```

​

However it tells me that all of my local variables used in `main.tf` are not known until after the apply?

​

I am then using my module like this:

```
module "network_acls" {
  source = "./modules/network_acls"
  network_acls = {
    "allowTrafficOfficeIPOutbound" = {
      priority                    = 100
      direction                   = "Outbound"
      access                      = "Allow"
      source_address_prefix       = "1.2.3.4"
      resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.acc_resource_group.name
      network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.network_acls.name
    }
    "allowTrafficOfficeIPInbound" = {
      priority                    = 101
      direction                   = "Inbound"
      access                      = "Allow"
      source_address_prefix       = "1.2.3.4"
      resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.acc_resource_group.name
      network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.network_acls.name
    }
  }
}
}
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here?

Comment: Are you missing `direction` in the `locals.tf`?

Answer (score 0):

In your resource you are mixing the local and the variable, that is not how it should be done, you should be using the local in the `for_each`
see this example:

```
resource "null_resource" "cluster" {
  for_each = local.network_acls
  triggers = {
    key = each.key
    direction = each.value.direction
    access    = each.value.access
    protocol  = each.value.protocol
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${each.key}"
  }
}
```

we call that module like this:

```
terraform {
  experiments = [module_variable_optional_attrs]
}

module "test" {
  source = "./testmod"
  network_acls = {
    "allowTrafficOfficeIPOutbound" = {
      direction = "Outbound"
      access    = "Allow"
    }
    "allowTrafficOfficeIPInbound" = {
      direction = "Inbound"
    }
  }
}
```

A terraform plan will output:

```txt
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.test.null_resource.cluster["allowTrafficOfficeIPInbound"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "cluster" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "access"    = "Deny"
          + "direction" = "Inbound"
          + "key"       = "allowTrafficOfficeIPInbound"
          + "protocol"  = "*"
        }
    }

  # module.test.null_resource.cluster["allowTrafficOfficeIPOutbound"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "cluster" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "access"    = "Allow"
          + "direction" = "Outbound"
          + "key"       = "allowTrafficOfficeIPOutbound"
          + "protocol"  = "*"
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

We can see the plan has the expected values

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some time I have made this work:

Module:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "this" {
  for_each                    = { for k, v in var.network_acls : k => v }
  priority                    = each.value["priority"]
  direction                   = each.value["direction"]
  access                      = coalesce(each.value["access"], local.network_acls.access)
  protocol                    = coalesce(each.value["protocol"], local.network_acls.protocol)
  source_port_range           = coalesce(each.value["source_port_range"], local.network_acls.source_port_range)
  destination_port_range      = coalesce(each.value["destination_port_range"], local.network_acls.destination_port_range)
  source_address_prefix       = coalesce(each.value["destination_port_range"], local.network_acls.source_address_prefix)
  destination_address_prefix  = coalesce(each.value["destination_address_prefix"], local.network_acls.destination_address_prefix)
  name                        = each.key
  network_security_group_name = each.value["network_security_group_name"]
  resource_group_name         = each.value["resource_group_name"]
}

locals {
  network_acls = {
    access                     = "Deny"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "1.1.1.1"
  }
}

variable "network_acls" {
  description = ""
  nullable    = false
  type = map(object({
    network_security_group_name = string
    resource_group_name         = string
    priority                    = number
    direction                   = string
    access                      = string
    protocol                    = optional(string)
    source_port_range           = string
    destination_port_range      = string
    source_address_prefix       = string
    destination_address_prefix  = string
    }
  ))
}
```

Call the module:

```
module "network_acls" {
  source = "./modules/network_acls"
  network_acls = {
    "allowTrafficOfficeIPOutbound" = {
      priority                    = 100
      direction                   = "Outbound"
      access                      = "Allow"
      source_address_prefix       = "1.1.1.1"
      resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.acc_resource_group.name
      network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.network_acls.name
      destination_address_prefix  = null
      destination_port_range      = null
      source_port_range           = null
    }
    "allowTrafficOfficeIPInbound" = {
      priority                    = 101
      direction                   = "Inbound"
      access                      = "Allow"
      source_address_prefix       = "1.1.1.1"
      resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.acc_resource_group.name
      network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.network_acls.name
      destination_address_prefix  = null
      destination_port_range      = null
      source_port_range           = null
    }
  }
}
```